# Why is overflow in css working with a delay?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to achieve a drop down cover effect (Not sure how it's really called) with the following code:

```css
.new_events_list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 26%;
  height: 28vh;
  background-color: #323642;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#new_events_list_effect {
  background-color: #ee5f95;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: -100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div.new_events_list:hover #new_events_list_effect {
  top: 0%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div.new_events_list:hover img {
  filter: grayscale(0.5);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="new_events_list" style="overflow: hidden;border-radius: 10px;">
  <img class="new_events_list" id="photo1" src="https://www.dpreview.com/files/p/articles/7395606096/Google-Photos.jpeg" alt="event_list_1" style=" object-fit: cover; width: 100%;border-radius: 10px;">
  <div class="new_events_list" id="new_events_list_effect">

  </div>

</div>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that once you hover over the photo the pink block drops down with the corners visible which only disappear after a second or so. Could anyone explain to me how I could possibly drop down the pink coloured div without the corners being visible? 
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: remove `background-color: #323642;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for your comment, but I still keep getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```css
.new_events_list {
  position: relative;
  width: 26%;
  backgorund-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}

.new_events_list_effect {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ee5f95;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: -100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.new_events_list:hover .new_events_list_effect {
  top: 0%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="new_events_list">
  <img src="https://www.dpreview.com/files/p/articles/7395606096/Google-Photos.jpeg" class="image">
  <div class="new_events_list_effect"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what has been done to fix the problem. Having to eyeball parse code can sometimes be difficult

Comment: Could you please explain me what I did wrong and why I was getting what I was getting?